# cant run python package after uploading to pip

Tags: python, pip, pypi

I have a python 3 package I'm trying to upload to pip called `vlcradio`, I upload it successfully, then download it with `pip install vlcradio`, but am unable to run it using `python -m vlcradio`, as I get an error saying:

```
C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe: No module named vlcradio
```

This is what the structure of my python package folder looks like:

```
/VLC-Radio/
    /.git
    /vlcradio
        __init__.py
        __main__.py
    LICENSE
    README.md
    setup.py
```

And these are my files:

```
#__ init__.py
name = "vlcradio"
```

.

```
#__ main __.py
import sys
import os
#libraries to help encode / decode utf-8 chars to their corresponding ascii
#from unidecode import  unidecode
from urllib.parse import unquote
import html
import html.parser
from shutil import copyfile
from sys import exit
import os.path
import requests
import time
from PIL import Image

###############################################
print("\n\nprogram start")
#... lots more code
```

setup.py

```
import setuptools

with open("README.md", "r") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()

setuptools.setup(
    name="vlcradio",
    version="0.0.1",
    author="martinbarker99",
    author_email="martinbarker99@gmail.com",
    description="export VLC metadata",
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    url="https://github.com/MartinBarker/VLC-Radio",
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    ],
)
```

inside the folder where `setup.py` is, I run these commands:

```
python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
```

Which creates the /dist folder successfully.

```
python -m twine upload --repository-url https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/ dist/*
```

I sign in and the package gets uploaded correctly, I can see it in my pip account online. Then in a different cmd window I run:

```
pip install vlcradio
```

Which installs correctly, but when I try to run it with:

```
python -m vlcradio
```

I get an error saying:

```
C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe: No module named vlc-radio
```

is there some step for specifying my package name that I'm missing? Thanks

Comment: That should be `python -m vlcradio`.

Comment: @KlausD.fixed typo, running 'python -m vlcradio' leads to same err

Comment: I was able to install it and run it (although, not sure of arguments). Can you share the exact error? I suspect you have 2 (or more) versions of Python installed. Can you try install it again but this time run: `C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe -m pip install vlcradio`, then try run it again.

Comment: `No module named vlc-radio`? Are you referring to the package as `vlc-radio` or `vlcradio`? It must be the latter.

Comment: had different versions of python running, uninstalled them and was able to get it working

Answer (score 0):

had different versions of python running, uninstalled them and was able to get it working